# How do you find the speed of an object knowing the co-ordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$ e.g. (2, 3, 4)?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, speed

How do you find the speed of an object knowing the co-ordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$ e.g. (2, 3, 4)?

Comment: You can't, the speed of the object is the time derivates of its coordinates, and not its current values.

Answer (score 2):

Your 4d coordinates​ refer to a single point at a single time. It's impossible to find its velocity unless we know a second to which it has progressed.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple one sentence answer - "You can't"

Now ask yourself this question. "Bobby is walking at Times Square. What is his speed?"

I bet you won't be able to answer that (Unless You are Bobby or You are standing next to him!!). The information I just supplied is insufficient. Speed is the rate of motion, or the rate of change of position. As far as the information I supply (and you've given) is concerned, there is no apparent data on motion.

Instead, You will have to specify two coordinates and the time the Object took to move from one to another (Or two separate space-time coordinates).

The speed in that case will be:

$$ v = \frac{\sqrt {(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}}{\Delta t} $$

Where (x1, y1, z1) denotes the first point, (x2, y2, z2) denotes the second point.

Well, this is the case for a linear motion. Things can get really complicated when it comes to other cases.

For a more general case, use this age old (and very basic) formula:

$$ v = \frac{dx}{dt} $$

where x(t) denotes the function governing distance as a function of time - t.